# Are you able to add grammer after RecognizeAsync on a SpeechRecognitionEngine?

Tags: c#, .net, speech-recognition

I am struggling to find any information on this in the docs but I have a use case where users can add new terms after the recognition system has started listening.

Most examples are like:

```
SpeechRecognitionEngine.AddGrammer(foo); // Do other setup stuff
SpeechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeCompleted += SomeHandler; // Setup listener
SpeechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

So in my scenario after this code has been run I potentially want to call `SpeechRecognitionEngine.AddGrammer(newFoo)` but nowhere details if this is supported or if there is a way to mimic this.

Worst case I can internally track the terms that have been added and then when a new grammer request comes in dispose current instance then recreate with new bits, but then the concern is that anything listening to the old `RecognizeCompleted` will no longer work and needs to be told to update too.

(Also incase anyone is wondering why im using this older library I need to have offline speech recognition in an application which limits my options, as its part of an open source framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around for ages it looks like there is a mechanism for this, you need to call `RequestRecognizerUpdate` which triggers the `RecognizerUpdateReached` event, and the recognizer hangs there for you to do any updates you need within that method before it continues.

```
// Setup with the listener
SpeechRecognitionEngine.RecognizerUpdateReached += OnUpdateRecognizer;
SpeechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

// The method that lets you update stuff
public void OnUpdateRecognizer(object? sender, RecognizerUpdateReachedEventArgs args)
{
    SpeechRecognitionEngine.LoadGrammar(whatever);
    // Do whatever else you want
}

// The method to call to trigger the update callback
SpeechRecognitionEngine.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
```